# ASP.net post form to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, post, webforms

I have a register page with the method:

```
public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when form to register is submitted
    /// </summary>
    protected void SignUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        // Various things that manipulate controls on the Register.aspx page
    }
...
```

This is the only page on the site where a user can register.

I now want to put a registration form on another page on the site with the same fields.  I want it to post to this registration page and run `SignUp`.

Changing `PostbackURL` to `Register.aspx` for the button doesn't appear to work as I need to invoke the `SignUp` method.

It's difficult to create a globally accessible class that does the same functionality as `SignUp` as the function manipulates controls on the Register page.

I could create a control to do a registration, but was wondering if there's an easy way to do it as described above.

Comment: Have you tried setting the CodeBehind (in .aspx) to share a common .cs file?  It can get a little tricky, but I've had success with that approach in the past.

Comment: I would go with a UserControl, as that's what they are meant for: re-useability.